# VueJS: How to embed the emoji component dynamically in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, electron, vue-component

How to embed the emoji component dynamically in contentEditable div while typing some text inside the div.

Here is the extract of my code:

```html
<picker set="emojione" @select="addEmoji" />
<div>
    {{ inputBoxValue }}
</div>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Some',
        components: {
            picker: Picker,
            emoji: Emoji,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                inputBoxValue: '',
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addEmoji() {
                this.inputBoxValue = ' <
                emoji emoji = "{ id: "
                heart_eyes ", skin: 2 }"
                set = "emojione"
                size = "16"
                tooltip = "true" / > ';
            }
        }
    }; 
<script>
```

Comment: Are you using vue2? I think you've miss tagged this as vue 1. Also if your using vue-electron you can tag that instead or alongside electron. Also node.js is probably not valid here.

Comment: Finally I think you need to use += in your addEmoji method so that you don't continuously replace whatever is inside inputBoxValue.

Comment: Infact have you considered using a computed property and looking at the string as a whole and then carrying out a replace on whatever is inside it? The problem with your current approach is that even if fixing it with += you have a problem where you can't really add random emoji's in where ever you want, like how a normal user would act.

Comment: I am not able to see 'vue-electron' tag, this is just sample code. So using '=' or '=+' doesn't add any value or info to the questions.

Comment: Every time you hit addEmoji the entire string is replaced, is this desired functionality?

Comment: Yes that's desired functionality but my point of view of question is how to add or call components through variables, or  is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking about the problem wrong here, instead of adding the components via a string into the dom you'll need to start using `v-for` and components. For instance if we create the following component:

```
<div>
    {{emojiText}}
</div>

<script>
    export default {
       props: ['id', 'set', 'size', 'tooltip'],
        name: 'InnerEmojiHolder',
        data() {
            return {
                emojiText: '',
            };
        },
        methods: {

        },
        ready(){
         // put logic to build emoji here using props
        }
    }; 
<script>
```

This can then be used inside of your existing component like so:

```
<picker set="emojione" @select="addEmoji" />
<div>
  <template :for="emoji, index in currentInput">
    <innerEmojiHolder :id="index" :set="emoji.set" :tooltip="emoji.tooltip" :size="emoji.size" : ></innerEmojiHolder>
  </template>
</div>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Some',
        components: {
            picker: Picker,
            emoji: Emoji,
            innerEmojiHolder: innerEmojiHolder,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                currentInput: []
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addEmoji() {
             // Push our emoji variables into currentInput
            }
        }
    };
```

This allows us to print out all of the emoji's using a for and will use the data from the parent inside of the child.